# const error message

Tags: c++

what does this error message mean :
error C2662: 'addDoctor' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const class Clinic' to 'class Clinic &'
I'm not using const though

sorry,but this is my first time posting experience

Clinic.h

```
class Clinic{
    public:
        Clinic();
        int addDoctor(Doctor*); 
    private:
        Doctor doctors[10];
        int d;
    };
```

Clinic.cpp

```
Clinic::Clinic()
    {d=-1;}
int Clinic::addDoctor(Doctor *x)
    {d++;doctors[d]=x;return d;}
```

Comment: Posting some code might help.

Comment: if there's a way to upload the source file that would be helpful but I'm new here I don't know how to post it .So if anyone knows let me know

Comment: Just insert the code snippet into the question and format it useing the "code" button on the toolbar.

Comment: @fresh-girl: Just post the relevant code into your question. Make it as long as necessary and as short as possible. To format the code correctly indent it with four spaces. The complete reference: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: A bit of code would probably help a lot with getting to your problem ...

Comment: ok here it is:
class Clinic{
private Doctor d[10];
private int index;
public void addDoctor(Docotr);};
Clinic::Clinic(){index=0;}
void Clinic::addDoctor(Doctor x){
d[index]=x;}
see,there is no const in the whole class yet it still gives me that error

Comment: You should rather click "Edit" below your question and insert the code into the question itself.

Comment: Also which line does the error message refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you are trying to call non-const member function `addDoctor` from a const member function.

EDIT: In the newly posted code, you have an array of `Doctor` objects but you are trying to put an pointer into that array.  That will give an error like can not convert from `Doctor*` to `Doctor`

Answer (score 3):

You have a const object and you are trying to call non const member function. All errors are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s2d2tez(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It means you are calling addDoctor on a const this without the function call being a const.

The variable you are calling addDoctor on needs to NOT be const.

Edit: A const member function looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   void MyNonConstFunction();
   void MyConstFunction() const;
};
```

const guarantees that you don't change anything inside the class.  I assume with addDoctor that is not the case.

Most likely you have something like the following

```
const Object obj;
obj.addDoctor();
```

This will break.  If you do:

```
Object obj;
obj.addDoctor();
```

Things will work.  Of course this gets more complex if you are calling it on the const return from a function.   If this is the case you need to get that object a different way.

Comment: that's the problem.The object I'm using is not const.
to be more clear it an array of objects as a data member of the class that contain that method

Comment: as you said the method here is not const that's right but the object is close to this
class some{
   private Doctor array[10];
   public void addDoctor(Doctor)
};
void main(){
Doctor x;
array.addDoctor(x);

}

Comment: th problem was that addDoctor was called in another method which is const.funny ha?! I don't know why I've put const there I don't even remember I did.thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s2d2tez(VS.80).aspx) example

```
// C2662.cpp
class C {
public:
   void func1();
   void func2() const{}
} const c;

int main() {
   c.func1();   // C2662
   c.func2();   // OK
}
```